# ¿Cómo asignar valores a LocalTime?

Tags: java, localtime

Estoy aprendiendo *Java* y tengo una pregunta. He revisado en varios sitios cómo asignar valores a `LocalTime`, pero no encuentro un ejemplo concreto, quiero decir, que mediante `Scanner` pueda asignarles la hora que desee y luego operar con ellos, cambiar los valores (2, 3, 45).

```
LocalTime lcl = LocalTime.of(2, 3, 45);
```

¿Es posible? y si es posible operar con ellos, por ejemplo, para el tiempo transcurrido entre horas distintas (a-b).

Answer (score 2):

Si entiendo bien su pregunta:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.time.LocalTime;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        int h;
        int m;
        int s;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("introduzca la hora");
        h = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("introduzca los minutos");
        m = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("introduzca los segundos");
        s = scanner.nextInt();

        LocalTime lcl = LocalTime.of(h, m, s);

        //System.out.println(h +" "+ m +" "+ s);

        System.out.println(lcl.getHour());
        System.out.println(lcl.getMinute());
        System.out.println(lcl.getSecond());
    }
}
```

*...que mediante Scanner pueda asignarles la hora que desee...*

```
        //variables para alamcenar los datos usando scanner
        int h;
        int m;
        int s;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("introduzca la hora");
        h = scanner.nextInt(); //almacenas el dato
```

creamos el objeto con los datos de la variables que asignamos con scanner:

```
LocalTime lcl = LocalTime.of(h, m, s);
```

Si usa el scanner para crear el objeto tenga presente esto:

---

```
public static LocalTime of(int hour,
                           int minute,
                           int second)
```

Obtains an instance of LocalTime from an hour, minute and second.
This returns a LocalTime with the specified hour, minute and second. The nanosecond field will be set to zero.

Parameters:

- hour - the hour-of-day to represent, from 0 to 23
- minute - the minute-of-hour to represent, from 0 to 59
- second - the second-of-minute to represent, from 0 to 59

Returns:
the local time, not null

Throws:
DateTimeException - if the value of any field is out of range

---

Las horas, minutos y segundos están indexada a 0, ademas de tener en cuenta eso tendría que comprobar que los valores que obtiene del scanner no están fuera del rango y cumplen con ellos ya sea con el uso `if` dentro de un bucle o lo que usted quiera.

*...y luego operar con ellos...*

```
//puede usar
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

//..

//supongamos tiene dos instancias
LocalTime suLocalTime1 = LocalTime.of(h, m, s);
LocalTime suLocalTime2 = LocalTime.of(10, 05, 03);

long hEntre = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(suLocalTime1, suLocalTime2);
long mEntre = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(suLocalTime1, suLocalTime2);

System.out.println(hEntre);
System.out.println(mEntre);
```

---

Puede hacer uso de [ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) con el método between puede hacer cálculos con objetos que implementen la interfaz `temporal`, y `LocalTime` es uno de ellos y calcular la cantidad de tiempo entre dos objetos temporales.

> between(Temporal temporal1Inclusive, Temporal temporal2Exclusive)

---

*... cambiar los valores (2, 3, 45)....*

[LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) es inmutable puede mirar los metodo que tiene.

Pero no se muy bien lo que quiere lograr, por ejemplo puede usar `LocalTime.plusHours(long hoursToAdd)` para obtener una nueva instacia, a la que se le añaden horas ect, quizas eso es lo que busca al decir de cambiar los valores.

---

P.D: quizás para el scanner podría usar parse `LocalTime leetTime = LocalTime.parse("10:10");` pero creo que solo funciona con Java 8.